# Luaotfload: change kerning for many characters at once

Tags: fonts, lua, luaotfload

How can I iterate over many characters? And how can I iterate over hexadecimal values?

Not working MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\directlua{function W(s) return string.gsub("[0xS]", "S", "s") end}

\directlua{fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
    name = "kerntest",
    type = "kern",
    data = {
        ["d"] = { for s = 61,69 do W(s) = 200 end}% example d and a-i
    }
}}

\begin{document}

\addfontfeature{RawFeature=+tnum}

da db dc dd

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since it's something you do once, you could consider simply to hardcode the whole alphabet, such as `["d"] = { ["a"] = 200, ["b"] = 200, ["C"] = 200, ["D"] = 200}`. A simple excel sheet with some formulas can help in writing the code quickly. But I know that in this forum there are some true specialists of font handling... so let's see if there's some better way.

Comment: here is an example that maps over a table: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/370809/2388